# Ruby: Shuffle index of an array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array I am running .shuffle! on, but it is only changing the order of the array, not the indexes.  See example:

```
arr = [3,5,7,8,2]
puts arr[0] => 3
arr.shuffle! => [5,2,8,3,7] #you would think this array is shuffled, however...
puts arr[0] => 3
```

despite being in a different spot in the array, the index still points to that number.  Anyone know how to shuffle and array so the index points to a different value?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Not reproducible here, either. I'm betting you excluded the `!`.

Comment: nevermind this whole question, it turns out i'm an idiot.  The shuffle function was working as it should, its just the way I formatted my output made me think it wasn't.  I did some additional debugging and saw what the issue was

Answer (score 1):

Your input definitely should not lead to that output -- when I type out what you typed out in the above irb session, shuffle! works as expected. Searching for explanations: did you definitely do `arr.shuffle!` and not just `arr.shuffle`?

(If you already know this, please ignore). Exclamation points mean that the method changes some object that already exists, as opposed to making a new object and returning it. So if you had typed `arr.shuffle`, the output above would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind this question.  See comment for situation.